# Tracking when a google sheet tab is opened

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create some metrics regarding how often people are using different sheets in my spreadsheet.

I have an On Open trigger that fires properly whenever someone  opens or refreshes the spread sheet.  Once the sheet is opened however, I would like to track each time they click a  tab and go to another sheet.  The simple On Open trigger does not fire when spreadsheet tabs are clicked.

Is there a trigger or another method that would allow me to track tab usage?.

Thanks,
Brett

Comment: In general, no, there is not. You'll need your own UI / application if you want to track analytics like that. There is a special case which depends on how you track these analytics: You could use a function that is triggered via `on edit`, and access the `e.range` parameter. This, however, still will not track **views** - only edits.

Answer (score 1):

We could use the edit and change installable triggers to track some changes made to sheets but they can't track certain users actions like opening a tab o clicking on a cell, among other actions.

References

- [Available types of triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers)
- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)